# How to fadeIn to fadeOut elements while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, uiscrollview

I have more than 70 divs on my page.

I don't want to show all the divs at once until user scrolls page.
I am trying to hide overflown elements on my page, while user scrolls the page , hidden divs should be fading in again.

But i am not able to hide overflown elements and not finding any way to fadeIn overflown elements again if window is scrolled.

However i gave it a try-

```
$(function(){
   $(window).css("overflow","hidden");
    var lengthy= $('.content').length;
         alert(lengthy);  

        var scrollbottom= $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height();

        $(window).scroll(function(){

             $(document).css("overflow","hidden");
            if($(window).height() >scrollbottom)
            {
                $(document).fadeIn();
            }
        });


});
```

## [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/QCcbH/)

How can this be done?

Comment: You want elements to fade in as they scroll into view, and fade out as they scroll out of view?

Comment: First, you cant set overflow:hidden on window, or document, use body for this! And second, you could use a plugin for this like: http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/infinite-scrolling-demo1/

Comment: YOu may want to use Ajax for that

Answer (score 1):

EDIT your Jquery to somthing like this

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
      //Add something at the end of the page
   }
});
```

What this does is the scroll happens when it's reaches 10px before end of page and not necessary the very end of the page. It's not necessary to have it, but it gives greater control to define at what point page should scroll...

This Example will show you what i think you want
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dnspinger/

Comment: USE THIS ARTICLE http://ajaxian.com/archives/implementing-infinite-scrolling-with-jquery